# How to call self host wcf service from asp.net client?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, console-application

I have a console app that self hosts a WCF service. When user access a asp.net application and clicks a button on a page, how to write some script to call this self hosted WCF service (the service hosted on local). I guess something wrong in my script, please help.

```
namespace SelfHost
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IHelloWorldService
  {
      [OperationContract]
      string SayHello(string name);
  }

  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
  {
    public string SayHello(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/hello");

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
        {
            // Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
            // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
            // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
            // by the service.
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Script to calling the service

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function invokeService() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userName = " test";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: "false",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello",
                data: "{'name':'" + userName + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                method: "SayHello",
                success: function (result) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(result);
                },
                error: function (retult) {
                    AjaxFailed(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the configuration file of your self-hosted service! That's where all the interesting stuff like binding and behaviors is configured - without that, we cannot help, really... but calling a self-hosted WCF service is no different than calling an IIS-hosted WCF service, really - just get the *ABC of WCF* right (**address, binding, contract**) and you're ready to go!

Comment: Was the console app running when you tried to call the service?

Comment: From your WCF service it appears that you are exposing a SOAP service using BasicHttpBinding. If you want to invoke your service from JQuery/Ajax and not building the complete SOAP message in your JQuery/Ajax it would be better exposing the WCF service using WebHttpBinding

Comment: Debug by chrome, it seems calling a self hosted service on local from script is cross domain, i will try to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hope to invoke a WCF service using jquery in this way.

The biggest problem is that you are exposing a ***Soap service*** and trying to invoke it using a ***rest-like client***.

Since .net 3.5, WCF allows you to expose WCF service operations to non-SOAP endpoints. You have to expose your service in this way to be able to consumme it with Jquery.

The starting point in MSDN ie [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412169%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and there was a good introduction  in [msdn magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) a few years ago.

A really simple example is (without any config)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string EchoWithGet(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string EchoWithPost(string s);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }

    public string EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
        ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found cross domain calling by script is not allowed. So another way is that have a command line app or console file to call wcf service. then register this app in registery. then launch the app from script.